# No internet connection even if it reports auto ethernet connection established

Tags: networking, internet

My internet connection on my ubuntu laptop was just working yesterday.  I don't recalling doing anything drastic that could affect networking settings.  However, I am now unable to connect to the internet and use firefox or ping to a website.  When I right click the network icon on the top right, it says the connection was established with Auto eth0.  What should I do to test what is happening? (  T _ T )  Thank you for your help~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connecting to ethernet does not ensure that your Internet is connected. Successful establishment of Auto eth 0 connection tells us that modem and ethernet port are now connected, but there is no information about whether modem is connected to internet or not. So the problem is with your modem, either reboot your modem, or ask the ISP that you are not able to connect to internet through modem. Sometimes restarting modem may work.

Comment: The modem works though because all the other computers on my lan have internet.  I'll try reboot the modem regardless..

Comment: ok then try to set dns settings to 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 and reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

If it's showing that connection is established it means that cable is plugged. I think you are having problems with DHCP. Try to set IP's manually.